# Calculating base and its increment over time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

I am looking to create an equation for calculating the result of: a base number `x` added to itself `n` times, each time incrementing up by another number (`i`). All of these values are arbitrary and will never be related to the value of another variable in this equation.

`50 + 52 + 54 + 56 + 58 + 60`

In the above example `x` is 50, `n` is 6, and `i` is 2. The output is 330, and my goal is to be able to calculate this given `x`, `n`, and `i`.

I understand that the formula begins with `x * n + r` with `r` being the relationship between `n` and `i`, however I'm not quite sure how to get there. My algebra is weak and I'm not certain if there is an operator that can sum up `i`'s relationship to `n`.

Comment: It would be worth making the question clearer: You want to calculate the result, not the base number `x` as you write in the first sentence.

Comment: Hint: how does $r$ look like if you spread it out as a sum? Does this remind you of anything?

Comment: or maybe a colon after the "calculating" allowing you to continue reading on @Thanassis

Comment: yes, it reminds me of factorials @Thanassis however what I am thinking of isn't quite exact.

Comment: hmm I am not sure how you got factorials. Just write in a comment the term $r$ as a sum.

Comment: r = i + (i+i) + (i+i+i) + (i+i+i+i) + ...... +(i + i + ...n times .... +i + i).  Can you figure out what that is?

Comment: @fleablood that's the issue, I in search of the operator that explains this (i + i) n times more simply. it's what I'm trying to figure out, but no, I don't know.

Comment: Start by rewriting .... + (i+i+i) + ..... as .... + 3i + .....  So r = i + (i+i) + (i+i+i) + ..... + (i+i+.... n-1 times + i) =  ... what?

Answer (score 3):

So you want $x + (x + i) + (x + i+i) + ......(x + i+i+i.....i)=$

$x + (x + i) + (x + 2i) + ...... + (x + (n-1)i) =$

$x + x + x + ....... + x + i + 2i + 3i + ...... + (n-1)i$

$n*x + i(1+...... + (n-1))=$

$n*x + i*\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=$

$n*x + i\frac{(n-1)n}2 =$

$n(x + i\frac{n-1}2)$.